# Retrieving data using Prepared Statement

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I've been trying to retrieve data from my database ( MySQL ). 
I've been looking for samples on the web, but nothing that matches what I'm trying to do, even on Stack. 
So here's what I tried :

```
public void RetrieveData()
{
    cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    //connecting to database

    Connect();

    try
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM storing WHERE id=1";
        cmd.Prepare();

        ResultSet rs = cmd.CommandText;
    }
}
```

But I have an error on the ResultSet saying 'ResultSet is not accessible because of it's protection level'
cmd is created in the class because I need it into my other functions.

Does anyone know what I should write ? 
I just want to retrieve all my data ( 5 columns in the database ) and print them in the console using this :

```
location = rs.GetString(2, @location);
Console.WriteLine("Location is : " + location );
```

That's an example, but I really don't know what to write.

Thanks in advance for the help guys !

Comment: Doesn't `CommandText` return a `string`?  How are you setting that to a `ResultSet`?

Comment: You've scoured the web and cant find an example of how to read 5 columns from a MySQL database? Nonsense.

Comment: I want to retrieve the data from the database with the PreparedStatement. I'm used to code in Java, not C#. And it seems to be totally different. 
I didn't manage to find anything that matches what I needed.

Comment: find any ADO.Net sample of which there are thousands or more. All the providers (MSSQL, MySql, SQLite, OleDb, etc.) work the same, you just use different classes (MySqlConnection instead of SqlConnection, for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the method that you are looking for is

```
... 
try
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM storing WHERE id=1";

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var location = reader.GetString(2);
        Console.WriteLine("Location is : " + location ); );
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this :

```
            String longitude = "";
            String latitude = "";
            bool status = false;
            String path = "";
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    longitude = reader["longitude"].ToString();
                    latitude = reader["latitude"].ToString();
                    status = (bool) reader["status"];
                    path = reader["path"].ToString();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Longitude : " + longitude);
            Console.WriteLine("Latitude : " + latitude);
            Console.WriteLine("Path : " + path);
```

The first time I tried it, it didn't work so I deleted it. And then I tried it again, and it works now. Don't understand what i did change from the odd version, but looks ok now.